# Grouping A List - Looking For A Better Way

Tags: c#, .net, linq

**I have a list something like that**

```
var x = new List<string>{"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
```

**I want to group it in doubles like that**

1-A

1-B

2-C

2-D

3-E

3-F

**What my solution is**

```
        var result = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        var sequence = 1;

        var groupList = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length ; i++)
        {
            groupList.Add(x[i]);

            if ((i + 1)%2 == 0)
            {
                result.Add(sequence, groupList);
                groupList = new List<string>();
                sequence++;
            }

        }

        return result;
```

**I am looking for alternative (better) ways to get same result.**

Comment: What is wrong with that way? Just wrap it in a function and be done with it

Comment: yea, what do you mean by "Better ways" ... what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Couldn't agree more. This looks fine, put the 2 in %2 in a variable and you can have any number of items in the group, that is group of x size.

Comment: Is this a _code to Linq_ request?

Comment: @AndreiV How can it be done by Linq

Comment: Who is upvoting this question?? explain yourselves!

Comment: @RyuKaplan was Linq your original idea for a solution? Judging from the tag, it was...

Answer (score 1):

This will do the same.

```
var y = x.GroupBy(i =>Convert.ToInt32((x.IndexOf(i) + 1.1) * 0.5));
```

Comment: Shorter form: `var y = x.GroupBy(i =>Convert.ToInt32(x.IndexOf(i)/2) + 1);`

Comment: That's indeed shorter and nicer to read. I always worry about the rounding when it's 0.5 as it's just on the edge. And the multiplication is just a habit from my embedded C days as it is slightly faster. Nowadays I guess the compiler will do that for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
    int numPairs = 3;
    char[] abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();         
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, char[]>();
    for (int i = 1, k=1; i <= numPairs && k<abc.Length; i++, k+=2)
    {
        dict.Add(i, new char[] { abc[k - 1], abc[k] });
    }
    return dict;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a readable Linq solution:

```
var result = x
      .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
      .GroupBy(arg => arg.index / 2 + 1, arg => arg.value);
```

The `Select` projects the value with its index into an anonymous type, and the `GroupBy` groups by the index.

If you need the groupings in a `Dictionary` like in your question, use `ToDictionary`:

```
var dictionary = result.ToDictionary(
      grouping => grouping.Key, 
      grouping => grouping.ToList());
```